# How to use Command Line Parser Library in case Error happend?

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, command-line-arguments

I use [Command Line Parser Library](https://commandline.codeplex.com/) to parse command lines parameters.

I have declared class `Options`

```
internal class Options
{
    [Option('r', "read", Required = true,
        HelpText = "Input file to be processed.")]
    public string InputFile { get; set; }

    [Option('f', "date from", Required = false,
        HelpText = "Date from which get statistic.")]
    public string DateFrom { get; set; }

    [Option('t', "date to", Required = false,
        HelpText = "Date to which get statistic.")]
    public string DateTo { get; set; }

    [Option('v', "verbose", DefaultValue = true,
        HelpText = "Prints all messages to standard output.")]
    public bool Verbose { get; set; }

    [ParserState]
    public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

    [HelpOption]
    public string GetUsage()
    {
        return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
            (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
    }
}
```

And this is how i try to use Parser :

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello and welcome to a test application!");

        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string fromDate = string.Empty, toDate = string.Empty;
        DateTime dateTo, dateFrom;

        Console.ReadLine();

        var options = new Options();
        if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options))
        {
            // Values are available here
            if (options.Verbose) Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", options.InputFile);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.InputFile))
            {
                filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
                {
                    filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Report.xlsx";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filePath = options.InputFile;
            }
            fromDate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.DateFrom)
                ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFrom"]
                : options.DateFrom;
            toDate = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.DateTo) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateTo"] : options.DateTo;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

//other code
    }

But in case of some error application just stop working.

So i want to know how to repeat first step of inputting values in case of error.

```
while (!CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)){...} - makes loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Command Line Parser as such.

Declare a common wrapper for multiple projects

```
public class CommandLineOptions
{
    public const bool CASE_INSENSITIVE = false;
    public const bool CASE_SENSITIVE = true;
    public const bool MUTUALLY_EXCLUSIVE = true;
    public const bool MUTUALLY_NONEXCLUSIVE = false;
    public const bool UNKNOWN_OPTIONS_ERROR = false;
    public const bool UNKNOWN_OPTIONS_IGNORE = true;

    public CommandLineOptions();

    public string[] AboutText { get; set; }
    [ParserState]
    public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

    [HelpOption(HelpText = "Display this Help Screen")]
    public virtual string GetUsage();
    public bool ParseCommandLine(string[] Args);
    public bool ParseCommandLine(string[] Args, bool IgnoreUnknownOptions);
    public bool ParseCommandLine(string[] Args, bool IgnoreUnknownOptions, bool EnableMutuallyExclusive);
    public bool ParseCommandLine(string[] Args, bool IgnoreUnknownOptions, bool EnableMutuallyExclusive, bool UseCaseSensitive);
}
```

Create an Application Command Line class for this application

```
public class ApplicationCommandLine : CommandLineOptions
{
    [Option('d', "download", HelpText = "Download Items before running")]
    virtual public bool Download { get; set; }

    [Option('g', "generate", HelpText = "Generate Mode (Generate New Test Results)", MutuallyExclusiveSet = "Run-Mode")]
    virtual public bool GenerateMode { get; set; }

    [Option('r', "replay", HelpText = "Replay Mode (Run Test)", MutuallyExclusiveSet = "Run-Mode")]
    virtual public bool ReplayMode { get; set; }
}
```

Main Program:

```
ApplicationCommandLine AppCommandLine = new ApplicationCommandLine();

try
{
    // Parsers and sets the variables in AppCommandLine
    if (AppCommandLine.ParseCommandLine(args))
    {
        // Use the Download option from the command line.
        if (AppCommandLine.Download) { 
            DataFileDownload();
        }
        if (AppCommandLine.GenerateMode) { 
            GenerateProcessingData();
        }

        ...

    }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The class CommandLineOptions is not a valid class. Is this meant as a generalization with the intention that the reader will know the 'obvious' items to replace/fill?

Comment: CommandLineOptions was the class I created as a wrapper for functionality to the CommandLineParser class.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is that when I take the source as is, and put it into Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, it identifies that the source isn't complete. I can be more specific. I also could be misunderstanding the usage.

Comment: Ah and for clarification, I do have a working implementation of Command Line Parser. Just not as you have implemented. I was curious if your usage of LastParserState  actually works. With my version, command line parsing errors never appears within the parser state. It remains @ zero.

Comment: Correct, there is code missing, which is what the ... is meant to imply.  This would be a basic outline of the code needed to help you understand the newer interface, then complete the additional sections that are missing on your own.  Let me know if there are areas that you do not understand or need help with.

Comment: Missed or invalid parameters do show errors and will generate the help screen.  However, I am not looking directly at the LastParserState though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess my point was, is that the file that does not have the ".." is the one with the problem. If you want to be precise, then the ... should go there. But even so it is difficult to see the direction. Apologies. Also, if you don't look @ LastParsrerState to see parsing errors, where do you look? -Thanks.

Comment: Basically the catch.  If the command line parsing throws the error, then I know to quit the program. It is a simple command line tool that uses the library and complex error handling with the command line is not there as we use it internally and do not really get bad options specified.